# jQuery .change value for multiple items matched on dynamically generated names/ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dynamic, onchange

I have a dynamically generated collection of multiple select / input pairs, with generated IDs.

*Stripped down:*

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
  <select id="option_<?php echo $matching_id; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
       <option title="<?php echo $inputvalue ?>"></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <input id="update_<?php echo $matching_id; ?>" type="text" value="" />
<?php } ?>
```

I have this jQuery to update the input field with the title attribute (have to use title since the value attribute is needed for something else) of the selected option:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').change(function() {
    $('input').val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"));
    });
});
```

Of course this is wrong. It updates ALL the input fields with the same value, regardless of which select box is changed.

I need only the input box with the matching ID number to change. The $matching_id variable is always a number, if that's relevant.

Can some helpful person point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[id^="option_"]').change(function() {
        $('input[id="update_' + $(this).attr('id').replace('option_', '') + '"]').val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"));
    });
});
```

Selects only `select`s when their `id` starts with `"option"`, doesn't require `$matching_id` to be numeric, necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('select').change(function(){
      $('#update_' + $(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g,'')).val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"));
   });
});
```

If any select changes, it goes and finds an element [input] with the id 'update_' plus the numeric part of its own id, and sets it's value equal to the selected option's title.